# Python webbroswer open url in same tab

Tags: python

I'm trying to open the broswer and search some urls with the module `webbroswer` of python,
This is my code

```
import webbrowser

b = webbrowser.get('firefox')
b.open('google.com')
b.open('stackoverflow.com', new=0)
```

This code works but it opens the urls in two different tabs, i want that it searchs before for google.com and after in the same tab it has to search for stackoverflow.com. I read in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) that for open a new thab the `new` parameter has to be set equal to 2 but it is 0 now, why it keeps opening new tabs?

Comment: `new=0` means the website is opened in the same browser window. It doesn't mean it's opened in the same tab.

Comment: and what can i do for open it in the same tab?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Change url of web browser using webbrowser-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443178/python-change-url-of-web-browser-using-webbrowser-control)

Comment: The doc is not clear for option 0 regarding the tab although I understand that it will "try" to open a new tab. There is a different approach explained here using Selenium https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269187/8753169

Answer (score 0):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('google.com', new = 0)
```

And the docs says:

> If new is 0, the url is opened in the same browser window if possible. If new is 1, a new browser window is opened if possible. If new is 2, a new browser page (“tab”) is opened if possible

The same question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443178/python-change-url-of-web-browser-using-webbrowser-control).

Comment: it does not work for me, `new = 0` or `new = 1` or `new = 2` is not different from each other

Answer (score -1):

try this:
webbrowser.open_new(url)
Open url in a new window of the default browser, if possible, otherwise, open url in the only browser window.

webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
Open url in a new page (“tab”) of the default browser, if possible, otherwise equivalent to open_new().

Comment: The question is "how do I load a new URL in an existing tab?" Neither of these choices answer that.

Comment: try this: script = 'open location "%s"' % url.replace('"', '%22')

Answer (score -1):

```
b.open('stackoverflow.com', new=0)
```

Your new should be set to 2 not 0.